# How can I modify text/shapes created early and have effects previously built on those elements propagate automatically?

Tags: gimp, workflow

I have an image with the effect of wooden text inlaid within another species of wood.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Woodworking]

I would now like to change the text. However, I would then need to reapply all of the layer masking, resizing and other effects that I made to the text to create this effect originally.

Is it possible to achieve a more elegant workflow where I can make changes to objects created early on and then all subsequent effects built on those objects propagate automatically? I think this is known as parametric design.

Comment: The key search term that I think might be helpful for you is "non-destructive"

Comment: With Photoshop, it's a simple matter to configure a layer style for the text and save that style. I don't know if GIMP offers any similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, yet.

In the current development cycle of GIMP (that's 2.9.x, to be released as GIMP 2.10.x) the foundations for non-destructive editing are laid. It is expected to have this in GIMP 3.x.